# What is the purpose of fetch.json file inside cordova plugins folder?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-cli

File **fetch.json** created inside plugins folder after **cordova plugin add** executed first time. This file also modified each time I add/remove plugins.

- What purpose of this file exactly?
- What tools use this file, when and why?
- Is there a way to restore plugins using fetch.json (try not to place plugins into repositiory)?
- Where can I find some docs about content of this file?

Content of fetch.json:

```
{
    "com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin": {
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git",
            "subdir": "."
        },
        "is_top_level": true,
        "variables": {}
    },
    "cordova-plugin-file": {
        "source": {
            "type": "registry",
            "id": "cordova-plugin-file"
        },
        "is_top_level": true,
        "variables": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at http://jbavari.github.io/blog/2014/06/24/managing-cordova-plugins-with-package-dot-json-and-hooks/ he explains the faulty in not being able to simply define your plugins as dependencies and shows a solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this file tracks installed plugins, their origin and revision, like npm package.json dependencies does, but for plugman. I guess and hope this should migrate to the npm standard soon.

This file is updated on cordova add/remove plugins (https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/e4e5904619bab05705d62bce92a4c4cd0d45bb82/cordova-lib/src/cordova/plugin.js#L272)

When we `cordova prepare`, cordova reads plugin list from `plugins/ios.json` (for ios), then, for each one :

- get the plugin infos from `plugins/fetch.json`
- try to find the plugin locally

looks like its not possible to restore plugins with this file. My workflow is :

- define plugins dependencies in config.xml
- remote platforms and empty plugins folder
- run `cordova platform add xxx`

this will refetch plugins as defined in `config.xml`

Looks like the only doc is the source code : https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=fetch

Comment: From IRC phonegap team : "Plugman uses it to decide if it needs to download or not. This file should be ignored."