# Cordova fetch plugins in mac

Tags: macos, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm newby with Cordova and with mac. I have a next issue: I need to fetch plugins to my project from fetch.json.

I'm doing next thing: `cordova prepare` and next `cordova platform add ios`
but it doesn't copy plugins to folder `/plugins`. Don't know why?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this question and its answer: [What is the purpose of fetch.json file inside cordova plugins folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285200/what-is-the-purpose-of-fetch-json-file-inside-cordova-plugins-folder). It sounds like it isn't possible to restore plugins using that file, as it (only) checks locally? Honestly, this is the first time I'd heard of the file. :-/

For building from the command line I normally use the command:
`cordova plugin add <plugin>`

for each plugin you are using. Usually this isn't a huge list, and the commands only need to be invoked once. After that, it's just a `cordova build` to compile.

If you're using PhoneGap Build, you define the plugins in the `config.xml` file. There's quite a bit of information on how to use the service and the parts of the config.xml file up on the site: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue it was because of I have installed Node 5, with Node 4 it works ok.