# Cordova build causing platform specific plugin code to be changed

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on a Cordova project. I have had to make customisations to some of the plugins I've imported in the platform specific folders i.e. Android and iOS. Now everytime I do a cordova build from the root folder level, it tries to remove those customisations that I have made to the plugins in the platform specific folders.
Any idea what is causing this or ways to get around this?

Comment: Can you please add more details ?

Comment: for this case you need to create your own plugin with updated changes

Comment: please look in to the steps http://www.santoshshinde.com/2016/11/steps-to-create-cordova-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have some customizations on your plugins, install that plugin as **local** plugin instead of **registry** or **git**, it avoid reloading from repos of the sources.

To make this you can modify **fetch.json** file in **plugins** folder.

Sample:

```
  "cordova-plugin-camera": {
    "source": {
      "type": "local",
      "path": "C:\\Vs\\Projects\\Myproject\\plugins\\cordova-plugin-camera"
    },
    "is_top_level": true,
    "variables": {}
  },
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285200/what-is-the-purpose-of-fetch-json-file-inside-cordova-plugins-folder)